How long does it take to saturate the water vapor pressure in a small enclosed space?
I am trying to create an as much humid as possible small enclosed space (like a zip bag).
If I leave more than required amount of water in the zip bag, how long does it roughly take to reach the equilibrium/saturate the water vapor pressure?
I guess it is related but I also wonder, since RH is very sensitive to temperature, how quick would it re-reach equilibrium when the temperature slightly (+-1C) changes?
Can I create a 100% RH environment like this or the (not perfectly closed?) zip bag or another factor would prevent this?

It would be substantially easier and faster to run some tests and see for yourself, than to try and use some theoretical formula that may be way off, because it was based on parameters that do not match your situation.  See if you can get a consistent answer if you repeat the experiment.

@RC_23 I needed a quick answer but I realized it might not be that simple to answer, so I already started doing experiments.

One can identify two main kinetics processes occurring here: evaporation at the surface and transport of the resulting water vapor within the bag. The slowest kinetics process regulates the speed of the total process. For example, heating the water doesn't immediately affect the humidity far away in still air, as vapor transport would be the limiting factor. In contrast, rapid air circulation doesn't immediately product a relative humidity of 100% because evaporation would be the limiting factor.
There is substantial literature on water evaporation from free surfaces; see Sartori, "A critical review on equations employed for the calculation of the evaporation rate from free water surfaces" for the history and nuances of various models. As a first pass, we might assume that the air directly adjacent to the water surface is at 100% relative humidity, i.e., that the kinetics of evaporation are sufficiently fast and that distribution of this vapor through the bag sets the characteristic process time.
If we assume that the bag contains still air, with negligible convection, the vapor transport process is one of diffusion. The characteristic diffusion time over a length $L$ is $t\sim\frac{L^2}{D}$, where $D$ is the diffusivity. After one time constant, we expect most of the concentration difference to be eliminated (i.e., the far end of the bag away from the water has shifted substantially from the initial relative humidity to 100% relative humidity); after several time constants, the process is nearly complete, and the system is essentially at equilibrium.
The diffusivity of water vapor in air at room temperature is about $2\times 10^{-5}\,\mathrm{m}^{2}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$. For a 10 cm bag, the characteristic time is thus about 500 seconds or 8 minutes. After 1500 seconds, say, this model predicts uniform 100% relative humidity. This time seems plausible for the longest one would have to wait, and the actual time might be much shorter if the air is circulated by shifting the bag. One could test the prediction with a small humidity sensor connected to a hobby microcomputer such as an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, for instance.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I am actually doing experiments since I have asked the question. What I am seeing is that starting from 45% RH (~24C), it quickly (in 10 mins or so) passes 80% RH inside the bag. However, from 80% RH to 90% RH, it takes around an hour or so, then after 90% RH it takes hours (from 90% to 97% almost 24h). If at the beginning the transportation is the limiting factor, after that, is the evaporation itself (being in a high RH environment) the limiting factor ?

Hmm. The simple asymptotic model above would predict ~93% RH after the second ~10 min and 97% RH after the third. I wonder if the bag is serving as a sink for water vapor, as everything is permeable to everything to some extent. A subsequent experiment could be to take the bag at nearly 100% RH, vent the air (to be replaced with drier air), and repeat the experiment with the same bag. If the result is different, then water storage within the bag material would seem to be a factor. Sound reasonable?

Yes, I think I need to make a bit more experiments and try also other/better bags or boxes.
